# C# Finding special chars in a filename

Tags: c#, regex, special-characters

I need to simply see if there are any matches for a group of special characters in a filename I have already tried all the common regex expressions including the ones below. All of these examples will find any special character except the brackets.

```
Regex.Match(filename, "[\\[\\]{}!@#]");
// I even separated this out into 3 like this
Regex.Match(filename, "[");
Regex.Match(filename, "]");
Regex.Match(filename, "[{}!@#]");

filename.IndexOfAny("[]{}!@#".ToCharArray()) != -1
```

What gives?

Comment: When you say special characters, what do you mean? What makes them "special" for your use case?

Comment: Brackets specifically break our system so we cannot allow a file with brackets be uploaded.

Comment: By "brackets", do you mean the square ones [ and ]? (The {} are called curly brackets by some.)

Comment: Both are illegal but {curly} is being found by any method I use, square [brackets] are the problem.

Comment: Try a regular expression test page, like [this](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx).  You may also want to look at [Regex Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/55c24bf1-2636-4f94-831d-28db8505ce00), an extension for Visual Studio.

Comment: Ill check out Regex Editor. I used this test page http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx and it confirmed the expression `[\[\]'~#%&*{}<>:?/|\\\"]` should work for me, but doesnt. I assume .net is breaking it along the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Regex.Match(test, @"[\[\]{}!@#]");
```

Works for me:

```
string test = "aoeu[aoeu";

Match m = Regex.Match(test, @"[\[\]{}!@#]");
// m.Success == true
```

Comment: This solves my bracket problem but how can I put a double quote " into the string literal to be checked?

Comment: Double it: `@"[\[\]'~#%&*{}<>:?/|\\@!""]"`

Comment: @TimeTravelMishap, double it.  The `@` symbol indicates the start of a [verbatim string literal.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution

```
filename.IndexOfAny("[]{}!@#".ToCharArray()) != -1
```

is perfect already. Leave escaping regular expressions to Houdini.